# Use of GPU drops after some batches using tensorflow fit

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, gpu

I am training a CNN using a large dataset. At the beginning (for the first ~200 batches with a size of 64) it says that it will last 1.5-2h to finish the epoch (~50,000 batches); however, when it reaches ~200 batches, the estimated time to finish the first epoch increases to about 20h. In addition to this increment of time, there is a drop in the use of GPU, which I guess is related to.

[image: Drop in the use of GPU]

I have checked some solutions, and I found that I had to use `gc.collect()` and `tensorflow.keras.backend.clear_session()` to release memory. Therefore, I am calling these commands after every epoch through a callback:

```
class ClearMemory(Callback):
    def on_train_batch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        gc.collect()
        tensorflow.keras.backend.clear_session()

H = m.fit(x=traingenerator,validation_data=validgenerator,epochs=n_epochs,shuffle=False,callbacks=[ClearMemory()])
```

However, despite using this, the estimated time still increases and the use of the GPU drops when reaching ~200 batches.

PS. I am using python 3.8, tensorflow 2.9.2, keras 2.9.0, CUDA 11.0 and cudnn 8.2.

Is there any solution I am missing to keep the same training speed for all the batches?

Thank you. Pablo.

Comment: Can it be that the computer overheats and drops the performance to cool down?

Comment: I don't really know, but it could be. I have checked that before dropping, the GPU's temperature reaches up to 66ºC. Few seconds after dropping, it is reduced 10-15ºC.